# Symfony Good practice : How to embed several forms for a single entity, handled by different controllers

Tags: ajax, forms, symfony, controller

I'm working on an application with Symfony 2 and I'm quite new with this framework.

I would like to create a page that represent an user profile on which users can update their personal information, set up an profile picture and a cover picture.

I've written the code for the User class and the template. For both profile and cover picture i'm using ajax with formdata to send images to server.

The other fields (username, email, etc.) are also sent with ajax, but all three parts (profile picture, cover picture, textual fields) of the form have their own submit button.

**My problem is about creating controllers and forms.**

- Should I create a controller for rendering the profile page and then one controller for handling the form ?
- Should I create a single form for all fields on the page or create three separated forms that would be handled separately ?
- Should I use formbuilder to create form(s) and in the case of there are more than a single controller, how to retrieve the form created in the first controller in the others to proceed validation
- Or maybe am I wrong from the beginning ... ?

I can provide my current code, but I don't think it can be useful since my User class and my template are very basic and I'm stuck on writing the rest of the code ; and I prefer knowing the "good" way of doing it before writing too much trash code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have many form and validate them in one controller:

```
public function updateAction(Request $request)
{

    $form_one = $this->get('form.factory')
            ->createNamedBuilder('form_one', 'form')
            ->add('user_picture', 'file')
            ->add('submit', 'submit')
            ->getForm()
            ->handleRequest($request);

    // Next form ...

     if ($form_one->isValid())
    {
        // Save user picture

       $data = 'user picture saved';
    }

    // Other forms validation

    return new JsonResponse(data);
}
```

Make sure to create the same forms in user profile controller view.

Comment: Does this mean I have to check each form with ``isValid()`` to know which one is being updated ?

Comment: Basically yes, but you can check fo form name in request.

Comment: In your example code I don't understand where the form and the entity are linked. Where do I have to specify the formType model ?

Comment: Sorry, form type is the second argument, and you pass entity as  third argument in `createNamedBuilder('form_name', 'form_type', $entity)`. But actually if you use form type, you can do it by normal `createBuilder` method while you form type have method `getName()`.

Comment: Ok. Thank you, I think it's quite more simple to use formType to be able to generate again the same form in both page controller and form handler controller. It seems to work find list this.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I use formbuilder to create form(s) and in the case of there
>   are more than a single controller, how to retrieve the form created in
>   the first controller in the others to proceed validation

You could make formType, like in this [example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html), there is `RegistrationType`.
Then use `formType` in different controllers.

Then you could validate form from entity(or whatever doctrine,propel or whatever you are using) using [entity validators](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html)

You could also check [generator bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/index.html), specially [Generating a New Form Type Class Based on a Doctrine Entity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_form.html)

Comment: formType sounds good but in my case is it better to create a single form for the whole page or create three different formTypes, one for each submittable "front" form ?

Comment: I quoted question, for witch I have answer ;) I'm not sure if I can provide good answer for multiple vs single form(s)

Answer (score 1):

Symfony best practices say to use custom form type classes for forms
[link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html)

I always use seperate controller actions for seperate forms. Code becomes more organized and is easier to debug. And I have had issues/bugs with multiple forms in same controller.

Comment: Thank you for your link, I didn't know about this 'best practice" section in Symfony's doc. However my code won't be "good" anyway since in my template I just don't use the Symfony form but I just send formData containing field with the same name to send images.